# How to display an UIImageView from a class

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a class named `myClass` with a `UIImageView` `imgView` and other vars. How can I display that view in the interface builder?

Sorry if the question isn't very exact, I'm new in iOS development. Ask me for any question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare it in myClass.h as an IBOutlet:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgView;
```

Then you can connect the outlet to the property in interface builder.  See the picture below for an example:

[image]

Comment: If you're using Xcode 4, you can create outlets directly from a nib by holding down control and dragging to the corresponding .h file.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can drag a UIImageView into your xib file, than hook-up with the IBOutlet UIImageView member class.
After you write the code bellow changing your image view variable.
The image you want to display must have to be inside resource or supporting files.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageName ofType:@"jpg"];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    imageView.image = image;

}
```